# Creating a method with char parameter in java

Tags: java, parameters, char, parameter-passing

If someone could break down these instructions id be very grateful (I'm new to java)

I have to write a method drawSeparators, and the parameter is the character that is going to be used for horizontal separators.... i need the - and = characters as separators. so far i have this (below) but don't know how to get it to actually work when called, once called i get 
  required: char
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

```
private void drawSeparators(char separator)
 {
 ta.append("----------------------------------------------------------");
 ta.append("==========================================================");

 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private static final int NUM_CHARS = 40; //number of chars to print
private void drawSeparators(char separator)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_CHARS; i++) 
    {
        ta.append(separator);
    }
}
```

to call:

```
drawSeparators('=');
```

Comment: You shall add `\n` at the end!

Comment: I left it out because he also left it out in his sample code

Answer (score 2):

```
private void drawSeparator(final char separator)
{
  for (int index = 0; index < SOME_NUMBER_OF_YOUR_CHOICE; ++index)
  {
    ta.append(separator);
  }
}
```

Comment: why do we need that `final` keyword in method argument?

Comment: it is not needed but I'm guessing he chose it to be explicit because this method is expected to not alter the requested char to be printed

Comment: I always use final for arguments.  It is a good habit, but one that is not universally accepted as good.  If your arguments are final, the compiler will flag any attempt to change them within the method.

Answer (score 1):

```
private final static int SEPARATOR_COUNT = <your_max_number>;

public void main(String[] args) {
    //
    //
    //
    // code
    //
    //
    //

    // When passing a character, make sure to use ' (char) and not " (String)
    // You can also make these characters constants, but that's up to you
    drawSeparators('-');
    // and/or
    drawSeparators('=');
}

private void drawSeparators(char separator) {
    for (int index = 0; i < SEPARATOR_COUNT; index++) {
        ta.append(separator);
    }
}
```